# Which class has the Highest DPS against tanks on wave 666?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-mann-vs-machine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [For each class, what are efficient methods to destroy the Tank Robot?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82714/for-each-class-what-are-efficient-methods-to-destroy-the-tank-robot)

Wave 666 has a lot of tanks and often many at a time. My team always loses due to lack of dps on tanks.

Which class with an upgraded weapon (or sentry) has the highest DPS against a tank over its full drive from one side of the map to the other?

Comment: iirc, upgraded melee weapons.

Comment: [This question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82714/for-each-class-what-are-efficient-methods-to-destroy-the-tank-robot) doesn't have all the classes worked out, but upgraded melee is needed for the highest dps, followed by a weapon with some way for additional damage.